# Why don't we always transpose the first tensor in a dot product?

Tags: tensor-products

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to understand why in one of the above equations we transpose "$e$" when making a dot product with "$E$", and I got it because of the order of the indices, but we could have avoided making a transpose if it was written this way: $e_{ijk}$ $E_{k}$

While in the other equation ***$\epsilon$*** wasn't transposed when multiplied with $E$

Comment: There is no reason to get a headache. These are just conventions. $e_{kij}E_k$ says sum over $k$ and $\epsilon_{ki}E_i$ says sum over $i$. Clearly the index position matters. Quite often people get confused when they think in terms of matrix multiplication. The latter we can write without indices, the tensor multiplication we cannot.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the part about summation over indices but why one gets transposed when written and the other doesn't

Comment: In tensor calculus there is no rule that says anything should be transposed. If it is clear what the tensor $e_{kij}$ is then it is clear what $e_{kij}E_k$ is. And it is clear that this is *not* $e_{ijk}E_k$ unless $e_{kij}$ has that symmetry.

Comment: Okay thanks, so I will not overthink it.